# Couchbase: Cannot perform operations on a shutdown bucket

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am getting this error when try to insert 2M objects via node.js into Couchbase. 1M works fine.

> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node_modules\couchbase\lib\bucket.js:
>   728 throw new Error('cannot perform operations on a shutdown bucket');

I am using Couchbase 3.0.1, node.js 2.0.2 SDK.

This is the code:

```
     var Couchbase = require('couchbase');

var myCluster = new Couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://10.0.0.103,10.0.0.102,10.0.0.101,');

var myBucket = myCluster.openBucket('rre');


   for (var i = 0;i<1000000;i++)
   {





    myBucket.insert('dwhtryrdue_'+i,  {
    "guid": "003dddbf-da50-46d4-a2aa-319677b5d2be",
    "CampaignID": 22,
    "ZoneID": 29,
    "AdvertiserID": 30,
    "BannerID": 36,
    "UserID": 32,
    "ClickIP": "Bette",
    "ClickHost": "Jerry",
    "ClickReferringURL": "Dejesus",
    "ClickDateTime": "2014-06-09T12:53:22 -00:00",
    "ClickCountry": "Central African Republic",
    "ClickState": "Kentucky",
    "ClickBrowser": "Chrome"
    }, function(err, res) {

    });

    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolved the issue by increasing the timeout: myBucket.operationTimeout = 120 * 1000;

Answer (score 7):

This error may also happen when there is a password set for the specified bucket.

To verify that open the Couchbase Console -> Navigate to the Data Buckets tab -> Drop-down your bucket -> Click the Edit button -> The third section in the popup dialog is Access Control, which has a password textbox.

Hope this helps,

György

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the compatibility between the `couchbase server` version and the `couchbase npm package` version.

On my machine:

1. The couchbase server was `4.5.1-2844 Enterprise Edition (build-2844)`.
2. The couchbase npm package version was `4.6.2`.

My soluton was simply downgrading the couchbase npm package back to `2.5.1` with: `npm i --save couchbase@2.5.1`.

Or you can upgrade the couchbase server version (haven't tested).

Answer (score 0):

I got the error in 2019, I resolved it by authenticating my cluster as now authorization should only be granted at cluster level but no need for bucket level authorization.

" cluster.authenticate('usernameForCluster', 'passwordForCluster'); "

Comment: This is probably not related to the question, because if you didn't authenticate properly, the first 1M wouldn't have been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate using USERNAME and PASSWORD, incase you setup a custom cluster.
So, in the code ...

```
var myCluster = new Couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://10.0.0.103,10.0.0.102,10.0.0.101,');
myCluster.authenticate('Administrator', 'adminadmin'); // Add this credential

var myBucket = myCluster.openBucket('rre');
```

By default, the USERNAME is **Administrator** and PASSWORD will be the cluster password(*adminadmin*, in my case).

P.S.-This solution is in particular to *Error: cannot perform operations on a shutdown bucket*